# Publishing Tools does not start in arcgis server 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, publishing

I'm trying to publish a service in arcgis server 10.1. In the last phase I encountered with this error: [image]

I tried to start the server as described in the error message. I encountered with this error:
[image]

error log:

```
<Msg time="2015-03-05T10:10:08,11" type="SEVERE" code="6550" source="Admin" process="6900" thread="1" methodName="" machine="FARZIN-PC" user="" elapsed="">Failed to start the server machine 'FARZIN-PC'. Could not start application server within stipulated time.</Msg>
<Msg time="2015-03-05T10:10:08,29" type="SEVERE" code="7701" source="Admin" process="6900" thread="1" methodName="" machine="FARZIN-PC" user="" elapsed="">Failed to start app server. Failed to start the server machine 'FARZIN-PC'. Could not start application server within stipulated time.</Msg>
```

I did everything to solve the problem but I failed. What do I need to do? BTW "FARZIN-PC" is my computer name.

Comment: Did you try restarting the server machine itself? And what error code are you getting in the logs? Thats usually a good place to start

Comment: Check Analyzing your GIS resources http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Analyzing_your_GIS_resource/01540000034m000000/

Comment: @Lou I added the error message in the log.

Comment: @Mapperz I already analyzed and I got no errors, just some warnings and messages

Comment: How is your set up configured?  It could be a permissions issue.  Check your server windows accounts and make sure they have permission to access the directory where you are storing your mxd or msd files for the service.  More info on permissions is here (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000002w5000000)